# Redirect user after authentication with OpenIdConnect in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am using OpenIdConnect provider with Owin/Katana for authentication in my asp.net mvc application. OpenIdConnect Provide authenticates users against Active Directory. I wanted to do a simple authorization check once the user is authenticated and redirect the user to another view.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Authority = "url",
            Scope="scopes",
            ResponseType = "response",
            ClientId = "clientid",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    var emailClaim = identity.Claims.Where(r => r.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).FirstOrDefault();

                    var user = dbContext.Users.Where(u=>u.Email==emailClaim.Value);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        //add user information to claims.
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.PersonId, user.Name.ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //redirect to a page 
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
             }
        });
```

How can I redirect the user if he is not in my database.

Comment: I was finally able to achieve this using custom Authorize attribute.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question, with a bit more elaboration, and mark it as the answer?

Comment: Sure and just posted my answer @pashute. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by writing custom AuthorizeAttribute and using it on every class in my application. In the custom authorize attribute I am checking for the a Claim which will be available if the authorization check is successful and redirecting the user to a separate view if not authorized.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if(UserClaims.PersonId == 0)
            {
                UrlHelper helper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);

                string url = helper.Action("Unauthorized","Error",null,filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme);

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

To add to the accepted answer in case someone battles with this like I did. I found that the following options worked for me -

Option 1

```
//redirect to a page 
context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = "Url";
```

Option 2

```
//redirect to a page      
context.HandleResponse();
context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
```

Be aware that the second option caused my HttpContext.User.Identity to be null. I suppose because HandlResponse discontinues all processing. Still useful if that is not a concern.

Comment: Option 1 is nice and clean

Comment: Option 1 is what I was looking for as I wanted the user to be signed in and also redirected.